# Dual map identity

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$U,V,W$ are vector spaces. For $A \in Hom(U,V)$, $B\in Hom(V,W)$, how can I show that $(BA)' = A'B'$? Should I consider the matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $f'$ is the dual map of $f$, you can do it as follows. Take $\alpha\in W'$. Then\begin{align}A'\bigl(B'(\alpha)\bigr)&=A'(\alpha\circ B)\\&=(\alpha\circ B)\circ A\\&=\alpha\circ(B\circ A)\\&=(BA)'(\alpha).\end{align}